# rectangle coordinates of Abbyy Cloud Ocr (Xml output)

Tags: python, xml, geometry, coordinates, abbyy-cloud-ocr

so im trying to extract data from invoices for that im using abby cloud ocr. im got the output as xml file now what i want to do is look for a text and take its rectangle cordinates and then look for closest rectangle and take its value
to do that i need the rectangle coordinates well the xml file actually return cordinates but i cant understand it

ill show u an example of the xml output (ill replace uneeded text with '....')

```
<line baseline="2062" l="2037" t="2033" r="2206" b="2064">....</line>
<line baseline="2101" l="295" t="2070" r="588" b="2097">....</line>
```

these are too different rectangles anyway i went to see the documentation and this is what is says

```
baseline — the distance from the base line to the top edge of the page
l — the coordinate of the left border of the surrounding rectangle,
t — the coordinate of the top border of the surrounding rectangle
r — the coordinate of the right border of the surrounding rectangle
b — the coordinate of the bottom border of the surrounding rectangle
```

what coordinate of the left border of the surrounding rectangle mean ?

isnt the rectangle coordinates on this format [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4]]?

can you explain to me what they mean by these coordinates or how can i use it ??

Comment: is this for text recognition?

Comment: yes it's for the text recognition

Comment: Can u post a sample output pls? with image